# JQuery code to rename a div

Tags: jquery, html, rename

Is there any method to rename a div element. I have a div with id fm`_`form`_`container,which lists a set of forms. If I click a link in a tab,for eg, My Forms, I want the name of this fm`_`form`_`container to change as tab`_`content`_`container. That is, all my forms should come inside the div, tab`_`content`_`container.

Is there any method to rename a div,like append and addClass?

**EDIT**

These are the css for the div id "fm`_`myforms`_`container and tab`_`content`_`container.

```
.tab_content_container
 {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFFFE1;
    border:1px #EEEEEE solid;
 }

 #fm_myforms_container
 {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:1px #EEEEEE solid;
 }
```

If I give,

```
$('#myForms').click(function(){

    //$("#fm_myforms_container").attr("id", "tab_content_container");

    $("#fm_myforms_container").addClass("tab_content_container");

    viewAllMyForms();  

});
```

the CSS for tab`_`content`_`container does not get applied.

Comment: Changing the id of the div can cause other codes that use the id not to work.

Comment: The CSS for the class looks pretty much the same as for the id. Check in firebug that the class is added.

Comment: The class was added when I viewed the code in firebug. Maybe since both the id,my_myforms_container and class,tab_content_container css's are present, I think the browser gets confused as to display which one as there is a slight color change alone. Anyhow, I changed my code in a different way, so this is not needed. But I learnt a concept from this, an ID (#) will only match a single element. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jQuery's attr method    :

```
$("#fm_form_container").attr("id", "tab_content_container");
```

Comment: Thank  you.. But I have another problem. When I click the Home Tab again, I need the id to be changed to fm_form_container. I did a $("#tab_content_container").attr("id", "fm_form_container"); when I click 'Home'. But the div name is changed only for the first div n not for the seccond and third. I have separated my forms into 3 types,and so have them as three sections. So the change is happening only for the first section and not the others.

Answer (score 5):

Where the My Forms link has a class of "myForms":

```
$(".myForms").click(function () {
  $("#fm_form_container").attr("id", "tab_content_container");
});
```

**Updated for comment to above answer:**

*"$("#tab_content_container").attr("id", "fm_form_container"); when I click 'Home'. But the div name is changed only for the first div n not for the seccond and third."*

This is because you're matching against an ID (#), and thus will only match a *single* element. If you want to apply your changes to multiple elements, you will have to apply them to a class, e.g:

```
class="tab_content_container" instead of id="tab_content_container"
```

Comment: Well, I had the tab_content_container changed to a class and added the class to that div using addClass method. But the CSS aren't getting added..

Comment: Are you sure that you've changed your CSS to reflect the fact that your divs are now part of a class, rather than using ids?
We'll need to see your CSS before we can diagnose that.